# Hibernate does not generate table with annotations

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm using Wicket in combination with Spring and Hibernate, at least that's what I'm trying to do, the problem comes with auto generating the tables with Hibernate annotations.

I've been trying many changes in the configuration but can't seem to figure out why my configuration doesn't generate any tables. And I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction, even about the Spring configuration I'm not sure.

I've included all the files I'm using to try to make this work in links, so that it won't be a very long list of configuration files.

I'm using the following class with annotations, http://schrealex.com/downloads/User.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="birthDate")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="profile_image")
    private String profile_image;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String password, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;

    }

    // Getter and Setter methods

}
```

I'm using the following dependencies described in my pom.xml:

http://schrealex.com/downloads/pom.xml

I'm using the following configuration in applicationContext.xml and properties:

http://schrealex.com/downloads/application.properties

http://schrealex.com/downloads/applicationContext.xml

And finally web.xml:

http://schrealex.com/downloads/web.xml

If I'm missing any files you'd like to see, just ask.

**Edit :-**

Added start up logging:

```
SSL access to the quickstart has been enabled on port 8443
You can access the application using SSL on https://localhost:8443

>>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP
INFO  - Server                     - jetty-7.6.3.v20120416
INFO  - tandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO  - /                          - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO  - ContextLoader              - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO  - XmlWebApplicationContext   - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1c35ce99: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Wed Nov 28 19:53:33 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader    - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
INFO  - XmlWebApplicationContext   - Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1c35ce99]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2a9b5441
INFO  - pertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from URL [file:/C:/Users/CE_REAL/Documents/Development/media-database/target/classes/application.properties]
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2a9b5441: defining beans [wicketApplication,placeholderConfigurer,dataSource,transactionManager,transactionInterceptor,managerTemplate,sessionFactory]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO  - Version                    - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
INFO  - Environment                - Hibernate 3.2.6
INFO  - Environment                - hibernate.properties not found
INFO  - Environment                - Bytecode provider name : cglib
INFO  - Environment                - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
INFO  - Version                    - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
INFO  - AnnotationConfiguration    - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
INFO  - notationSessionFactoryBean - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
INFO  - earchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
INFO  - ConnectionProviderFactory  - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.5.16-log
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.21 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
INFO  - Dialect                    - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO  - TransactionFactoryFactory  - Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
INFO  - actionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC batch size: 15
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Scrollable result sets: enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Connection release mode: auto
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  - ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query language substitutions: {}
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Second-level cache: enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query cache: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Echoing all SQL to stdout
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Statistics: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Named query checking : enabled
INFO  - SessionFactoryImpl         - building session factory
WARN  - ConfigurationFactory       - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/Users/CE_REAL/.m2/repository/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/1.2.3/ehcache-1.2.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
INFO  - essionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
INFO  - SchemaExport               - Running hbm2ddl schema export
INFO  - SchemaExport               - exporting generated schema to database
INFO  - SchemaExport               - schema export complete
INFO  - ContextLoader              - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 671 ms
INFO  - ContextHandler             - started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/CE_REAL/Documents/Development/media-database/src/main/webapp/},src/main/webapp
WARN  - WebXmlFile                 - web.xml: No url-pattern found for 'filter' with name 'wicket-spring-hibernate'
INFO  - WebXmlFile                 - web.xml: url mapping found for filter with name wicket-spring-hibernate:
WARN  - WicketFilter               - Unable to determine filter path from filter init-param, web.xml, or servlet 3.0 annotations. Assuming user will set filter path manually by calling setFilterPath(String)
INFO  - Application                - [wicket-spring-hibernate] init: Wicket core library initializer
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IFormSubmitListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener.onFormSubmitted()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=ILinkListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.ILinkListener.onLinkClicked()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IOnChangeListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IOnChangeListener.onSelectionChanged()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IRedirectListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IRedirectListener.onRedirect()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IResourceListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IResourceListener.onResourceRequested()]
INFO  - Application                - [wicket-spring-hibernate] init: Wicket extensions initializer
INFO  - WebApplication             - [wicket-spring-hibernate] Started Wicket version 6.2.0 in DEVELOPMENT mode
********************************************************************
*** WARNING: Wicket is running in DEVELOPMENT mode.              ***
***                               ^^^^^^^^^^^                    ***
*** Do NOT deploy to your live server(s) without changing this.  ***
*** See Application#getConfigurationType() for more information. ***
********************************************************************
INFO  - WebXmlFile                 - web.xml: url mapping found for filter with name wicket.media-database: [/login/*]
INFO  - Application                - [wicket.media-database] init: Wicket core library initializer
INFO  - Application                - [wicket.media-database] init: Wicket extensions initializer
INFO  - WebApplication             - [wicket.media-database] Started Wicket version 6.2.0 in DEVELOPMENT mode
********************************************************************
*** WARNING: Wicket is running in DEVELOPMENT mode.              ***
***                               ^^^^^^^^^^^                    ***
*** Do NOT deploy to your live server(s) without changing this.  ***
*** See Application#getConfigurationType() for more information. ***
********************************************************************
INFO  - AbstractConnector          - Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
INFO  - SslContextFactory          - Enabled Protocols [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] of [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
INFO  - AbstractConnector          - Started SslSocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8443
```

**Edit :-**

I tried renaming my User class to MediaUser and the @Table annotation to mediaUser to avoid problems with the USER word being reserved for some databases.

What I've found from the start up logging, as seen above, is that it does say it's running the export:

```
INFO - SchemaExport - Running hbm2ddl schema export 
INFO - SchemaExport - exporting generated schema to database 
INFO - SchemaExport - schema export complete
```

Also tried different approaches to the Hibernate annotations, like using other imports, @Table is now used by importing javax.persistence.Table, but I also tried the Hibernate org.hibernate.annotations.table, thus far without a solution to my problem.

Comment: What's the value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in your hibernate config?

Comment: The value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is create

Comment: Where is `hibernate.cfg.xml` ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani what should be in hibernate.cfg.xml? I'm quite the beginner what comes to configuring these things.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani he don't need hibernate.cfg.xml !,see applicationContext.xml sessionFactory bean

Comment: @CE_REAL can you post code related to creating table?

Comment: What does it mean "does not generate table"? Do you see any errors related to missing tables? In other words, are you sure that Hibernate gets initialized in your test scenario?

Comment: Please print errors which you may be getting

Comment: @invariant The Hibernate annotations should be generating the tables by themselves, at least that's what I read about it. The only thing needed to make this happen should be: 
`<property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    <value>com.schrealex.model.User</value>        
  </list>
</property>`

Comment: @BhavikAmbani I've added my startup logging, but I can't seem to find any errors, maybe I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer to my problem, the annotations need either be set on the instance variables or on the class and it's methods and it needs to implement Serializable like:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String email;
    private String profileImage;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String password, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;

    }

    // Getter and Setter methods

    @Column
    public getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Column
    public getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Column
    public getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    @Column
    public getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    public getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    @Column
    public getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Column
    public getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ... in my case, the problem was because the USER word is reserved for some data bases.

So, considering that your hibernate configuration files are right, just add a prefix in all your tables and the problem was solved.

I hope this solve your problem too =)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. I renamed my User class to MediaUser and the @Table annotation to mediaUser and still nothing happened.
It does say it's running the export.
`INFO  - SchemaExport               - Running hbm2ddl schema export
INFO  - SchemaExport               - exporting generated schema to database
INFO  - SchemaExport               - schema export complete`

Comment: are you sure , <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >true</prop> and see the queries going

Comment: user is a reserved keyword in most databases, so use something like user_table in @Table annotation

Comment: @SubinS Like I said, I renamed the table annotation and the class to mediaUser and MediaUser. That didn't help.
The property does say true, but it doesn't show me any queries, that's probably why there isn't a table created, but I can't find the solution to why it isn't generating queries/sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
@EntityScan({" yourentitypackagehere "})
```

in your springboot application