# in memory db hibernate spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I have been trying to integrate between spring and memorydb in junit tests but i keep getting the  exception.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not  found:    ORDERTABLE
```

testcontext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<jdbc:embedded-database id="testDataSource" type="HSQL">
</jdbc:embedded-database>
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bidblaze.service.test"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    </bean>



<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource">
    <ref bean="testDataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value= MYPACKAGE />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">

             <props>    
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:projectdb</prop>

            </props>
        </property>

  </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

with defining the other beans

My service class:

```
                 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
           @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/testContext.xml" })
           @Transactional
           public class TestService {
        //ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                //"spring-config.xml");
        @Autowired
        PaypalPaymentsService PaypalService;

        @Autowired
        private OrderDAO orderDAO ;
        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        private Session extSession;
        @Before
        @Transactional
        public void openSessionExternal() {
            extSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        @Test
        @Transactional
        public void shouldHaveASessionFactory() {
            assertNotNull(sessionFactory);
        }
        @Test
        @Transactional
        public void shouldHaveASession() {
            assertNotNull(extSession);
        }

        @Test
        public void saveOrder(){
            Order order = new Order();
            order.setOrderId("1");
            order.setRecieverEmail("enduser_biz@gmail.com");
            order.setAmount((double)2.00);
            extSession.save(order);
            Order testOrder = (Order) extSession.createQuery("from OrderTable where  orderId = ?").setParameter(0, "1").list().get(0);

            assertNotNull(testOrder);

        }
```

the Order class :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="OrderTable")
    public class Order {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="orderId")
String orderId;
```

PS: my Order class has other properties that refer to other classes but i didnt map them neither they are entities as well.
any suggestions

Comment: Looking at the 2nd half of that error - does [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612021/hibernate-does-not-generate-table-with-annotations) help?  Does your Order class implement Serializable?

Comment: at first it didnt but now i saw your comment i made it implement Serializable and tried to run the junit test, it still give the same exception

Comment: Do you have a no argument constructor?  The other answer dropped the table/column names in favor of naming by convention.  Does it work if you drop the Table and Column annotations and change the field to "id" (from orderId)?  Also, do you really want a String id in Order (as opposed to a numeric type)?

Comment: i tried to map this class using XML file and it worked, i dont know what is the problem with my annotations.    <class name="Package.Order"
  table="OrderTable" >
  <id name="orderId" type="string">
   <column name="orderId" sql-type="bigint" />
   <generator class="native"></generator>
  </id>
  
  <property name="status">
   <column name="status"></column>
  </property>
  
 </class>

Answer (score 0):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081044/hibernate-how-to-set-sql-type-by-annotation), and knowing your XML mapping, I'd suggest the following annotation changes to orderId:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="orderId", columnDefintion="BIGINT")
String orderId;
```

That's assuming that `@GeneratedValue` equates to a "native" generator as in your XML.  You might need to use an `@GenericGenerator` instead with a strategy=native instead more like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="my-native-generator")
@GenericGenerator(name="my-native-generator", strategy = "native")
@Column(name="orderId", columnDefintion="BIGINT")
String orderId;
```